# Formula To Find Total For Individual Items Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a simple program in which I have 2 tables. *Table A* lists all the relevant items. *Table B* is for placing Client requests. As you can see, the **Requested Items** column on *Table B* contains a drop-down list with all the predefined items in *Table A*. There is also a column stating the quantity request for each item.

[image]

I am thus trying to create some sort of dynamic formula, which will be able to find all occurrences of a particular item in *Table B*, whilst calculating the sum of the Quantity for each of these occurrences, and put that value in the "Quantity Requested column in *Table A*. A simulation with manually-input data can be seen below:

[image: *Table A* with sorted data]

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this structured formula at the column `Qty Requested` of `TabelA` (in any cell).

```
=SUMIFS(TableB[Qty],TableB[Requested Item], [@Item])
```

This structured format exploits very well the tables; it automatically fills the column and it will adjust whenever any of the two tables grows, shrinks, changes location, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Use Sumif in C8 write:
`=SUMIF(G:G,B8,H:H)`
G:G is the column of Requested Item in Table B
H:H is the column of Qty in Table B
B8 is the Item in Table A
You can drag the formula down